# AsyncTask when is onPostExecute() not called?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to ensure that I account for all possibilities to avoid errors for the user.

I have a AsyncTask that implements an interface and returns a response to the calling class in onPostExecute of the AsyncTask as below:

```
public class GetVideoInfoFromDataBase extends AsyncTask {

    Context context;
    private AsyncInterface asyncInterface;

    // Paginated list of results for alarm database scan
    static PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> results;

    // The DynamoDB object mapper for accessing DynamoDB.
    private final DynamoDBMapper mapper;

    public GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(Context context, AsyncInterface asyncInterface){
        mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
        this.context = context;
        this.asyncInterface = asyncInterface;

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        System.out.println("The backgrond stuff is working 1");
        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
        results = mapper.scan(AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter.class, scanExpression);
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object obj) {

           asyncInterface.response((PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> )obj);
    }
}
```

Is there any time that onPostExecute would not be called meaning the interface would not return a value?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The `onPostExecute ` should be called. Why not `System.out.println` something in `onpostExecute` to make sure whether it called.

Comment: it is calling fine.

Comment: I am asking is there ever a situation that would cause it not to be called.

Comment: `onPostExecute` method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled. In such situation, `onCancelled(Object)` being invoked on the UI thread after `doInBackground(Object[])` returns.

Comment: Thanks, so if my database call fails it will still run with a null? Assuming I add a try catch and catch the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPostExecute()` will run as long as `doInBackground()` returns and you did not cancel the task explicitly (by calling `cancel()` on your `AsyncTask` instance).

Technically, `onPostExecute()` will get called after (and if) the following line gets executed successfully:

```
return results;
```

As long as your process does not get killed in the meantime.

If you've cancelled your task, `onCancelled()` will be invoked  instead of `onPostExecute()`.